# How to add videos in WordPress custom page template ?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

For Posts you can avail the embed option provided by WordPress and that's easy. But for Custom page template is there any simple solution ? So far I've found this - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_add_provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Found these two solution -

One -

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[embed width="100%" height="500"]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ[/embed]'); ?>
```

Two -

```
<?php
$videourl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ';
$htmlcode = wp_oembed_get($videourl); 
echo $htmlcode;
?>
```

For some reason the first one didn't work for me but the second one did.